# Check Outlook email using Exchange Web Services (EWS)

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

Outlook Anywhere is not enabled on the Exchange server used at the company I work for.

People using Outlook on the Mac are able to get their mail remotely using EWS but i can't find any information on doing this in Outlook running on Windows 7.

The Exchange Server is 2010, does anyone know if I can use EWS to send/receive mail from Outlook in Windows 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Windows is irrelevant.  All Windows versions of Outlook connect to Exchange via MAPI (unless of course you're using Outlook Anywhere, POP, or IMAP).

Earlier versions of Mac Outlook (certain versions of Entourage) used WebDAV via the Exchange virtual directory.  Later versions of Entourage/Outlook 2011 starting using EWS.

Outlook for Windows isn't capable of this (as far as I know) but why would you want it to?  MAPI works well and accessing mail via EWS is more taxing on your Exchange server.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, i understand all of that. The situation is that outlook anywhere is not enabled on our corporate network for external connections but EWS is. This policy won't be changing.

Comment: Right, I was just trying to convey that mail through EWS is a Macintosh Outlook feature; Windows Outlook doesn't do this.  Your alternatives are POP or IMAP unless you want a completely different angle like a VPN.  That's not to say another client couldn't accomplish this though.  I recently ran into an issue with a certain mobile app being able to connect to Exchange 2007 mailboxes via WebDAV over the /exchange virtual directory (even though EAS, OWA, RPC/HTTP, IMAP, and POP were disabled).